# I want to make a regex which will match Maximum 3 digits optional, at the start with four words maximum one word minimum with spaces following it

Tags: c#, regex

`enter code here` I want to make a regex which will match Maximum 3 digits optional, at the start with four words maximum one word minimum with spaces following it.

Using C# Code

```
^\d{0,3}\s



 School
    This is a School
    1 This is a School
    145 Is this a School
    1450 Is this a School
    This is Govt Hight School
    
    
    School=True
    This is a School=True
    1 This is a School=True
    145 Is this a School=True
    1450 Is this a School=False
    This is Govt Hight School=False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?:\d{1,3}\h+)?\D\S*(?:\h+\S+){0,3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2HCLm/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:\d{1,3}\h+)?`: Match 1 to 3 digits followed by 1+ whitespace. This group is an *optional* match
- `\D\S*`: Match a 1+ non-space word that must start with a non-digit
- `(?:\h+\S+){0,3}`: Match 1+ whitespace followed by 1+ non-space word. Match 0 to 3 of this non-capture group
- `$`: End

Comment: It allows more than 3 digits

Comment: That's not correct. It doesn't match `1450 Is this a School` line

Comment: But it should be return false, if no word after the digit

Comment: How to prevent it from accepting one letter with one space each side of it (one letter word)? I meant that each word's letter limit should more than 1 letter.  example: This is a School=false    This is the School=true

Comment: Just use `^(?:\d{1,3}\h+)?\D\S*(?:\h+\S{2,}){0,3}$`